# Call to a member function format() on a non-object in Symfony2 (Doctrine)

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the some bug in my controller.

I'd config the entity by this config:

```
pv\MyBundle\Entity\NewsAuthorHistory:
  type: entity
  table: news_authors_history
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      column: id
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    date:
      type: datetime
      nullable: true
      column: date
    author_id:
      type: integer
      unsigned: true
      column: author_id
      nullable: false
    news_id:
      type: integer
      unsigned: true
      column: news_id
      nullable: false
  manyToOne:
    news:
      targetEntity: pv\MyBundle\Entity\News
      joinColumn:
        name: news_id
        referencedColumnName: id
    author:
      targetEntity: pv\MyBundle\Entity\Authors
      joinColumn:
        name: author_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

I have this code in my controller

```
$history_event = new NewsAuthorHistory();
$history_event->setAuthorId($author->getId());
$history_event->setNewsId($news->getId());
$history_event->setDate(\DateTime('now'));

$em->persist($history_event);
$em->flush();
```

But, If I try to run this code, I have the the

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in
>   /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php on line
>   53

I'd read a lot of posts about this error, but could not find a suitable solution for me.

**UPDATE:**
Some magic! O_o I added the following code to the file DateTimeType.php

```
if (!method_exists($value, 'format')) {
  var_dump($value); 
  var_dump(debug_backtrace()); 
}
```

And here the magic begins… To the date field filled… with information about csrf-token. 
How? Why? — I don't know… :(

Unfortunately, I could not resolve the problem. I solved this problem by SQL-code generation and directing its implementation in the entity-manager.

Comment: Some magic! O_o I added the following code to the file DateTimeType.php 
`if (!method_exists($value, 'format')) {var_dump($value); var_dump(debug_backtrace()); }`

And here the magic begins… To the `date` field filled… with information about csrf-token. How? Why? — I don't know… :(

Comment: I suspect your entity relations are all messed up.  You should not have both a news_id as well as a news relation.  Maybe update your question with the NewsAuthorHistory code.  Consider also bringing down a fresh project then work your way through the doctrine chapter until you have a working understanding of Doctrine 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
$history_event->setDate(\DateTime('now'));
```

should be

```
$history_event->setDate(new \DateTime());
```

Your error is that you're not instantiating a `DateTime` object that is what your entity expects. Moreover remember that `now` is default argument for `DateTime`.

### Edit

Could you try, just before creating a new `DateTime` to insert this snippet of code?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); //Just an example to understand what's going on
```

Comment: Yes, i'd try a lot of solutions:
`$history_event->setDate(new \DateTime('now'));`

or

`$now = new \DateTime('now');
$history_event->setDate($now);`

and

`# Entities/NewsAuthorHistory.php 
class NewsAuthorHistory {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->date = new \DateTime('now');
    }
}`

Comment: @Dmitry: and my solution doesn't work? I could not believe it!

Comment: I can't believe it, too.

Comment: @Dmitry Could you inspect your log error file? I'm pretty sure your php interpreter will report an error due to  default time zone settings

Comment: I found a little bit of magic in this code. Look to comment of the post.

Answer (score 0):

following your update I modified my convertToDatabaseValue in DateTimeType.php to this:

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    if(is_array($value)){
        $value = date_create($value['year'].'-'.$value['month'].'-'.$value['day']);
    }
    return ($value !== null)
        ? $value->format($platform->getDateTimeFormatString()) : null;
}
```

Now it works.